# What's the correct pattern for Immutable and Reselect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js, reselect

Let's say I have the following code and let's say `state` is from Redux and for some reason `state` is not yet an Immutable.js object. The problem just cascades and becomes so verbose.

```
export const helloWorldSelector = createSelector(
  initialState,
  state => state.get('greetings') // yields .get is an undefined function 
);

export const japaneseGreetSelector = createSelector(
  helloWorldSelector,
  state => state.get('ja')
);

export const englishGreetSelector = createSelector(
  helloWorldSelector,
  state => state.get('en')
);
```

I could make a fallback like so, but this still create problems for the subsequent selectors that depend on this one.

```
export const helloWorldSelector = createSelector(
  initialState,
  state => state && state.get('greetings')
);
```

Now if I had longer chain, then I would have to do something like this:

```
export const helloWorldSelector = createSelector(
  initialState,
  state => state && state.get('greetings', new Map())
);
```

This is so wet and tedious that I am starting to doubt this pattern. I must be doing something wrong, what is the correct way/best practice to use Immutable.js with Reselect?

Comment: I dont understand why would state be not immutable one moment and immutable in an other. is that the desired behaviour

Comment: @jstuartmilne Initialization isn't in immutable and I have no control in editing that part of the codebase. I can re-run an initialization myself from my side, but where would I run that code before mapStateToProps runs?

Comment: The sample code confuses me. `createSelector` is from reselect, there are no "plain" selectors and the input to `createSelector` should be a function, not an object? Does the root state really change from plain object to immutable? why would or should it?